# Best Solution, framework or technology to make apps for android and iphone

Tags: iphone, android, frameworks, mobile

I want to make app for android and iphone "writing once" and run in both.

Despite hardware, OS and native interface differences between this two platforms there is a special technology to make this easy, or I need to think in web apps with only html5, for example?

I read a bit material related with rhodes, titanium app and a others frameworks, but I don't know if is better to spend time studying the sdks and native tools or to invest in only solution. It's worthwhile?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a one off app and wont be doing a series of apps in different areas (games, content/music, LBS etc) then you are better off with using an existing framework. Otherwise you may want to build a platform of reusable components that you can leverage to quickly create apps.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use Titanium - once you get past a certain level of complexity you really are much better off making a native program. Its like desktop cross platform toolkits (Qt, Wx) - it never looks *quite* right on different platforms - multiply this x 100 for mobile, with a huge performance loss.

Both Android and iPhone support C, with POSIXy standard stuff (especially sockets, etc). You can do your logic in C/C++ and UI in ObjC/Java. Games are better off in C/C++ anyway due to performance. The user visible part "works right", while your "business logic" is identical across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap - http://phonegap.com/ is a very popular solution to your problem.
Single code base for iOS/Android/BB/etc.